# Selectinput is not taking the given values and does not update the table properly

Tags: r, shiny

I have the dataframe below

```
x <- data.frame(CategoryA=c("First", "Second",
                                   "Third" ),
                CategoryB=c("First", "Second",
                                   "Third"),
                Frequency=c(10,15,5))
```

The shiny app which I use should take the `CategoryA` values as inputs and update the datatable based on this selection. The first issue is that the `selectInput()` takes 1,2,3 as inputs instead of "First", "Second","Third" and of course does not update the table properly.

```
#ui.r
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('k-means '),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("inv")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("tab1")
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
function(input, output, session) {
  output$inv<-renderUI({
    selectInput("tow", label ="Suburb", 
                choices = c(unique(x$CategoryA)),
                multiple = T)
  })


  datasett<-reactive({
    tmp1 <- x %>% 
      filter(x[,1] == input$tow )
    tmp1
  })
  output$tab1<-renderDataTable({
    datasett()
  })
}
```

Comment: The use of `selectInput(..., multiple=TRUE)` and `filter(x[,1] == input$tow)` is wrong on two counts. (1) If you need multiple, then use `%in%` instead of `==`. (2) In `dplyr::filter`, you should be referring to the column name, you should never use the variable name as an indicator. While it can work (and likely will if you only heed my first step), it will certainly fail if the data coming into `filter` is grouped, pre-filtered, or anything other than *exactly as `x` appears outside the pipe*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `stringsAsFactors = F` -

```
x <- data.frame(CategoryA=c("First", "Second",
                                   "Third" ),
                CategoryB=c("First", "Second",
                                   "Third"),
                Frequency=c(10,15,5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

also -

```
datasett < -reactive({
    tmp1 <- x %>% 
      filter(CategoryA %in% input$tow )
    tmp1
  })
```